# How to embed the videos into website without their own site details?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating one website for e-learning and i need to embed the videos into the site. If I'll embed it works good but the videos contains that own site details like that site name (Youtube) and the control buttons of their site at the right corner.. I want to hide that source site details using HTML or Javascript. Could anyone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Sandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host the videos on your own website and then use a self-hosted video player. Some examples are below.

- http://jplayer.org/
- http://www.videojs.com/
- http://html5video.org/
- http://www.jwplayer.com/

There are more listed here: http://html5video.org/wiki/HTML5_Player_Comparison#All_Players